# Backbone events between view and controller

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to use Backbone events in a Model-View-Controller pattern. My controller is just a JavaScript class, so I've extended it like this to support Backbone events:

```
function Controller() {
    _.extend(this, Backbone.Events);

    this.listenTo(view, 'some:event', this.onSomeEvent);

    this.onSomeEvent = function() {
        // ... This code never executes.
    }
}
```

My view is a Backbone view that does this when a button is clicked:

```
onClick: function() {
    this.trigger('some:event');
}
```

The `onClick()` method executes in response to the button click, but the `onSomeEvent()` method of the controller never executes. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.onSomeEvent` should be defined before the call `this.listenTo`. Right now `this.onSomeEvent` is undefined when assigned as a listener.

You could also define your controller like this

```
function Controller() {
    _.extend(this, Backbone.Events);

    this.listenTo(view, 'some:event', this.onSomeEvent);
}

Controller.prototype.onSomeEvent = function() {
    // code
};
```

and call the controller like this `new Controller()`